# Переопределение методов. C#. Можно ли заменить обычными методами

Tags: c#, функции, override

Я не совсем понимаю, зачем нужна такая штука как переопределение функций (Override).
Например, у меня есть класcы Animal, Cat, Dog, Cow:

```
public class Animal {
    public virtual void activity () {
        // выпонять действие Х
    }
}
public class Cat : Animal {
    public override void activity () {
        // Мяукать
        // Мурлыкать
        // Бояться собак
    }
}
public class Dog : Animal {
    public override void activity () {
        // Гавкать
        // Защищать дом
        // Слушаться команд хозяина
    }
}
public class Cow : Animal {
    public override void activity () {
        // Говорить: "Му"
        // Давать молоко
        // Щипать травку на лугу
    }
}
```

В данном случае каждое животное имеет свой собственный метод activity, и каждый выполнит то, что расположено в его личном методе activity. Когда я пишу override, то я полностью переписываю метод (не так ли), а значит, что то, что изначально было в родительском классе Animal в методе activity (а это было "Выполнить действие Х") ни одно из животных (классов-детей) не выполнит.
Возникает вопрос: зачем делать один общий метод, после чего полностью прописывать его же для всех животных по отдельности, если можно так же прописать этот же метод для всех животных по отдельности, но уже не писать этот метод в родительском классе (таким образом я не пишу этот метод в классе Animal, а также не пишу слово override во всех детях). В чем смысл переопределения методов, если я все равно полностью их переписываю для всех унаследованных классов?

P.S. Прописывание слова virtual в методе родительского класса - это синтаксис языка С#. Однако переопределение методов есть и в С++, и Javа, и в Python должно быть, да и вообще во всех ООП языках. Так что этот вопрос не относится только к языку C#

Comment: внутри переопределяемого метода ты можешь обратиться к базовому методу через `base.activity()` например. Плюс не всегда базовому классу вообще нужна реализация метода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вы могли написать универсальную функцию и использовать её для любых животных. Обычно такое делается в виде метода в самом классе Animal, но для понятности пусть будет просто функция:

```
public make_animal_happy(Animal animal)
{
   animal.feed();
   animal.activity();
   animal.pee();
   animal.sleep();
}

var cat = new Cat();
var dog = new Dog();

make_animal_happy(cat);
make_animal_happy(dog);

// если реализация такой функции сделана в классе Animal, то ещё объектнее выглядит:
cat.make_animal_happy();
dog.make_animal_happy();
```

Как вы сделаете такое без перегруженных функций - будете писать для каждого вида животных копию одной и той же функции?

Хотя если дефолтная активность животного вам не нужна, то тут больше подойдёт реализация интерфейсов, а не перегрузка функций. Но бывает и так, что функция базового класса тоже нужна зачем-то, случаи разные бывают. Например, если поведение некоторых животных не отличается от базового, то можно реализовать функцию в базовом классе и не перегружать в классах для этих животных. А в других классах животных, где поведение другое - перегружать.

Comment: То есть я могу использовать make_animal_happy для любого животного, которому именно эти вещи нужны для "счастья", а например, для робо-собаки я могу уже переписать этот метод (добавив что-то типа, залить масла, зарядиться, прочистить шестеренки), и тогда функция этой робо-собаки будет отличаться от остальных. Правильно?

Comment: @МаксимФисман Ну да, но надо грамотно продумывать иерархию, кого от кого лучше наследовать, какие функции сохранить, какие переписать. Как унаследоваться так, чтобы поменьше функций переопределять. В вашем случае надо будет сделать make_animal_happy тоже виртуальным методом, который можно переопределить в классе-наследнике.